# Armazenando em um vetor sem apertar ENTER a cada inserção

Tags: array, c++

É necessário armazenar em um vetor uma sequencia de números, mas apertando o ENTER só no final da linha.

**Por exemplo:**

> ```
> ENTRADA: 10 20 30 15 50 <ENTER>
> ```

```
Vetor[] = {10, 20, 30, 15, 50}
```

Comment: Em qual linguagem vc deve fazer isso? não esqueça de colocar a tag dela.

Comment: Desculpa. É c++

Comment: Poste sua tentativa de implementação também, a idéia é obter ajuda, não pedir que alguém implemente isto para voce.

Answer (score 0):

Se está a utilizar c++ pode utilizar um `vector` que é simples para poder ir adicionando números à medida que os lê.

Quanto à leitura em si pode fazer de várias formas. Uma das mais diretas é com `stringstream`. Neste cenário a leitura pode ser toda feita do `cin` de uma vez só com [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) e colocada numa `stringstream`. De seguida vai lendo numero a numero da *stream* até terminar e adicionando ao `vector` com o método [`push_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/).

Implementação:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> nums; //criar o vector de numeros
    std::string linha; //string para ler a linha toda da consola
    std::getline(std::cin, linha); //ler a linha

    std::stringstream ss; //criar a stream
    ss << linha; //colocar a linha na stream

    int num;
    while (ss >> num){ //le numero da stream testando se chegou ao fim
        nums.push_back(num); //adiciona o numero ao vector
    }
```

Agora para mostrar pode utilizar o *ranged for loop* de c++11 por exemplo:

```
    for (auto n : nums){
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
    }
```

Caso não esteja a utilizar c++11 ou posteriores pode sempre utilizar o `vector` de uma forma bem clássica:

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i){
        std::cout << nums[i] << std::endl;
    }
```

Saída:

```
10
20
30
15
50
```

[Veja o código a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/FWmx6V)